# javascript from ajax doesn't get proper execution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Using Ajax, I've created a sort of console that allows me to execute some PHP functions dynamically.

It looks like this [image: screenshot]

The problem is that after a bunch of commands, the console becomes hard to read. So I've created a javascript function, named "wipe();", which clears the `<div>` containing the console.

I tested this function with the developpers tools of chrome (the javascript console) and it works perfectly.

But when I try to call this function by making the PHP-AJAX return a "<script>wipe();</script>", it doesn't work. It does nothing.

I've read on the internet that all the "<script></script>" works independently from each other, but that **you can call a `<script>function</script>` from another <script></script> block**.

So why is it failing to do that ?

here is the php code :

```
    echo '<script>wipe();</script>';
```

and here is the the first <script> block:

```
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var span = document.getElementById("screen");

     function send(data) {
        window.setInterval(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('screen');
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlhttp.open("GET", "./_rcons-transmetter.php?data="+data, true)
           xmlhttp.onloadend = function() {
             span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML+escapeHtml(data)+'<br>'+xmlhttp.responseText+'<br><br>';
           }
           xmlhttp.send();
         }

    function wipe(){
             span.innerHTML = '';
        }
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: No console errors. Nothing at all, in fact. Like everything's working perfectly (but it's not).

Comment: do a console.log(span) in the wipe function body

Comment: The console.log does not appear in the console when I call it from AJAX, but does appear when I call it from console.

Comment: script tags are ignored when set through innerHTML

Comment: How You call <script>wipe();</script>?

Comment: based on the code fragment you've posted, `wipe` will be a function that is **within** the `setInterval` callback within the `send` function - the script tags you are attempting to load using XHR are **not** able to access the locally scoped function - so even if you fix the innerHTML script issue, you'll still have no access to `wipe` from a dynamically loaded script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid security issues ( like a [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cross-site%20scripting) attack)  HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted via innerHTML [should not execute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0).

A way to execute the script is to evaluate the html using  [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) . Be warned: using eval can be dangerous.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var span = document.getElementById("screen");

function send(data) {
  window.setInterval(function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('screen');
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "./_rcons-transmetter.php?data=" + data, true)
      xmlhttp.onloadend = function() {
        span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML + escapeHtml(data) + '<br>' + xmlhttp.responseText + '<br><br>';
        evalJSFromHtml(span.innerHTML);
      }
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function wipe() {
      span.innerHTML = '';
    }

    function evalJSFromHtml(html) {
      var newElement = document.createElement('div');
      newElement.innerHTML = html;

      var scripts = newElement.getElementsByTagName("script");
      for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
        var script = scripts[i];
        eval(script.innerHTML);
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: In case is not used properly it can generate security issues (ex: xss ) . There are a lot of threads regarding this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil )

Comment: I'm very surprised this answer is accepted - evalJSFromHtml has no access to `wipe` function within the send function!

Comment: @JaromandaX - I believe "eval" function only don't have access to the global function if it's in strict mode. Since he's not in strict mode it should be fine.

Comment: `eval` can be used inside strict functions and still have access to the global environment, one just has to use a weird syntax to do an *indirect eval* -- `(null, eval)("alert(1)")`

Answer (score 0):

Call the 'wipe' function as a callback function directly from the 'send' function. Check status = 200 for a success response.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var span = document.getElementById("screen");

 function send(data) {
    window.setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('screen');
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.open("GET", "./_rcons-transmetter.php?data="+data, true)
       xmlhttp.onloadend = function() {
         span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML+escapeHtml(data)+'<br>'+xmlhttp.responseText+'<br><br>';
       }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
      {
        wipe(); // 'Wipe' callback function
      }
    }
       xmlhttp.send();
     }


function wipe(){
         span.innerHTML = '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**But when I try to call this function by making the PHP-AJAX return a "wipe();", it doesn't work. It does nothing.**

try create script tag and add to document rather than change inner html.

```js
var spaScript = document.getElementById("spaScript");
var wraper = document.createElement("div");
wraper.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = wraper.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].innerHTML;
spaScript.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: see Niks post approach rather than my post.

Answer (score 0):

Test if `wipe()` is in the input and if it is trigger it instead of the ajax call

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var span = document.getElementById("screen");

    function send(data) {
      if (data.indexOf('wipe()') == -1) {

        window.setInterval(function() {
            var elem = document.getElementById('screen');
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "./_rcons-transmetter.php?data=" + data, true)
            xmlhttp.onloadend = function() {
              span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML + escapeHtml(data) + '<br>' + xmlhttp.responseText + '<br><br>';
            }
            xmlhttp.send();
          }
        } else {
          wipe();
        };
      }

      function wipe() {
        span.innerHTML = '';
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

inserting a script tag directly inside an element should not work (and by the way generating an error in the console).

Using the native eval() function on the response text without speciying the tag attribute should solve the problem.

on server side

```
echo 'wipe()';
```

on client side

```
eval(xmlhttp.responseText)
```